# Appcelerator run error: You do not have access to this application

Tags: appcelerator-studio

I'm currently running an app I purchased from a template site for Alloy.  When I run the app I get the error you do not have access to this application.  Here are the steps I did.
1. I imported the app as existing project.
2. I hit Run in both debug and regular run on iPhone 7.
The error appeared after "Alloy compiler completed successfully".

I'm on an indie account and I'm new to this so I'm not sure how it should work.  The plus sign on the dashboard is locked where it says "Register App for services".  I'm not sure if this is the reason why I get this error.  I've checked online and I haven't found any solutions.

Answer (score 7):

Just remove **guid** attribute from the bottom of '**tiapp.xml**' file and let Titanium Studio creates a new one for you after running the app.

Answer (score 6):

I actually got a response to this from Slack and it worked for me.  Just thought I'd leave it in case someone else had this issue.

If it doesn’t work your account may be broken somehow. Try re-registering the app by generating a new guid and removing the appc-id from tiap. New guid you can create using `uuidgen` in terminal.

Also another recommendation given was: run `appc new --import` and it should move the app to your org. appstore etc works fine with indie

Comment: Hi @FabricioG, would it be possible to show the exact cli commands required?

Comment: @Joe Niland hi I just added it to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new Project, open `tiapp.js`, copy `guiid`, open your project and paste `tiapp` to the same location.

Answer (score 0):

For me no one of these solutions work, this was because I previously updated the tiapp.js file with the current repository and someone changes the IDs of the project to new ones, and I was not been added to the list of those developers that had permissions with the new IDs of that group, so I was added and then it works.

I know this is a rare situation but I have to mention it if there is some other case like mine.